# Trigonometry - Addition and subtraction theorem

Tags: trigonometry

If $\theta$ and $\phi$ are angles between $0°$ and $90°$, and $\sin \theta=3/5$ and $\tan \phi=7/24$, find without the use of a calculator, the value of each of the following:

a. $\sin(\theta−\phi)$

b. $\cos(\theta+\phi)$

c. $\tan(\theta−\phi)$

Please help, homework!

Comment: can someone please show me working out as well. thank you (Can be brief)

Comment: See this:http://geometri-problemleri.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/some-useful-angle-aproximations.html

Comment: Our policy is only giving hints, no complete solutions. Do you know any formulas that might be useful here?

Comment: I am sure this doesn't require double angle thereom

Comment: Trigonometric Addition Formulas? - i cant write them there too long.

Comment: Look at the first value you need to compute. Surely you must remember an identity involving precisely this expression!

Comment: sin( - )= sin  cos  - sin  cos 

Comment: sin( - )= 3/5 cos  - sin  cos 

Comment: what than do i use cofunctions?

Comment: What values involved do you know and what values do you not know?

Comment: cos  = sin (90 - ) ? am i on the right track?

Comment: Don't try to apply identities at random, think logically :) You must examine each value separately and find a way to compute it. In this case, there is a much simpler way of arriving at $\cos \theta$.

Comment: 0<<90 , 0<<90

Comment: Why is this important here?

Comment: your making me feel dumb ? hint? exact values possibly?

Comment: It's called Socratic method, and it's the best way to help someone learn :)

Comment: Can you get $\cos \theta$ just from $\sin \theta$?

Comment: easier way to find cos θ ?

Comment: is that a cofunction i dont know about?

Comment: so cos θ = sin θ ?

Comment: No, don't try to guess. Think instead of an identity that involves both $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$, something simple...

Comment: tan θ = sin θ/ cos θ surely ? - change subject ?

Comment: Go through your list of trig identities and find the one that's going to be useful here. If you can't come up with it from memory, I'm afraid it's the only way :)

Comment: that wont work?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Trigonometric_functions

Comment: The article seems fine to me :)

Comment: please just tell me which identity ? :( i feel like a year 7 retard!

Pythagorean Identity?

Comment: How do you intend to use Pythagorean identity to compute $\cos \theta$ knowing only $\sin \theta$?

Comment: i am officially a retard -.-?

Comment: sin θ +-SQUAREROOT 1 - sin2* θ ? if this isn't it well i don't know then just kill me.

Comment: No, you just lack self-confidence :)

Comment: Yes, that's the right formula! Well, almost right - you've made a mistake transcribing it :) Now plug the numbers in to get $\cos \theta$.

Comment: Find without the use of a calculator says the question though. But thank you for sticking with me through my stupidity.

Comment: Well, maybe you won't need the calculator...

Comment: okay let me see, i'll try to work on it. if i don't get can i come back and will you be still here?

Comment: I'll stick around.

Comment: cos θ = 4/5 ? yes?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Now, to the other values in the formula!

Comment: well thank you for your help!

Comment: This really should have been taken to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin\theta=\frac35$,$\cos \theta=\frac45$,$\tan\theta=\frac34$ and $\sin\phi=\frac7{25}$,$\cos \phi=\frac{24}{25}$,$\tan\phi=\frac7{24}$
(using Pythagoras therom we can find out any trigonometric ratio.  )

## part a.

$$\sin(\theta-\phi)$$
this formula will be useful:$\sin(A-B)=\sin A.\cos B-\cos A.\sin B$
$$\sin(\theta-\phi)$$
$$\sin\theta.\cos\phi-\cos\theta.\sin\phi$$
$$(\frac{3}{5}).(\frac{24}{25})-(\frac{4}{5}).(\frac{7}{25})$$
$$\frac {44}{125}$$

## part b.

$$\cos(\theta+\phi)$$
this formula will be useful:$\cos(A+B)=\cos A.\cos B-\sin A.\sin B$
$$\cos(\theta+\phi)$$
$$\cos \theta.\cos \phi-\sin \theta.\sin \phi$$
$$(\frac{4}{5}).(\frac{24}{25})-(\frac{3}{5}).(\frac{7}{25})$$
$$\frac35$$

## part c.

$$\tan(\theta-\phi)$$
this formula will be useful:$\tan(A-B)=\dfrac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A.\tan B}$
$$\tan(\theta-\phi)$$
$$\dfrac{\tan \theta-\tan \phi}{1+\tan \theta.\tan \phi}$$
$$\dfrac{\dfrac34-\dfrac{7}{24}}{1+(\dfrac34)(\dfrac{7}{24})}$$
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{11}{24}}{\dfrac{117}{96}}$$
$$(\dfrac{11}{24})(\dfrac{96}{117})$$
$$\dfrac{44}{117}$$